# Laravel: Error trying to populate drown down select from database

Tags: laravel, select

AuthController.php - I don't know how to pass the data to the view doing it this way. Should I even be doing this here or should I create a new controller?

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $departments = Department::lists('deptName', 'id');

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'deptartmentId' => $data['dept'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

My view

```
<div class="form-group">
     {{ Form::select('dept', $departments) }}
</div>
```

I also tried creating a function but I get an error saying the $departments variable is undefined in the view file

```
public function getDepartments()
{
    $departments = Department::all(['id', 'deptName']);

    return view('AuthController.getDepartments', compact('id', 'departments'));
}
```

Comment: AuthController.getDepartments  ,  do you have a getDepartments view or Authcontroller folder in your ressources/views/ folder?

Answer (score 1):

$departments variable is undefined in the view file because you are not returning a $departments collection with the view ,

this will work

```
public function getDepartments()
    {
        $departments = Department::all(['id', 'deptName']);

        return view('folder.theviewname')->with('departments',$departments);
    }
```

Comment: can you set the question as answered ? on left side of the answer under the voting , press the V